# In Python, how to ensure only one value is true?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A user may provide X query params to a web API, for example:

param_a

param_b

param_c

```
param_a = self.req.params.get('param_a', None)
param_b = self.req.params.get('param_b', None)
param_c = self.req.params.get('param_c', None)
```

If a given query param is not provided then its value is None.

They must provide at least one and no more than one or the params.

In Python 3, what is an effective way to confirm that at least one and no more than one param was provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count them up.

```
sum(x is not None for x in (param_a, param_b, param_c)) == 1
```

Since `True` has the value of `1`, the sum will be the number of parameters that are not `None`.

Comment: I like the brevity of this answer although I have to admit I found it a bit hard to understand the logic in a skim read. i.e. "x is not None" means in effect that this is a list comprehension that looks like [x is not None for x in (a, b, c)] which returns [True, False, True].  I like the way that works but I'm just saying it wasn't immediately obvious at a glance and since I am not super smart I tend to look for code that is obvious at a glance. I may go with your solution. [(x is not None) for x in (a, b, c)] is a little more skim-readable to me.

Comment: You can write `[(x is not None) for x in (a, b, c)]` in other languages like `Java` or `C#`, but shouldn't write that in **Python**. ;). The form like the answer of Ignacio is the best, in my opinion

Comment: @julivico interesting, I would have thought that explicit is better than implicit and I find the brackets around the "(x is not None)" to be more explicit.  I guess it's just personal preference though.

Comment: @Duke: Yes, you are right. But don't forget `Simple is better than complex` and may be `Flat is better than nested`. I think, the code of Ignacio is enough clear. Everyone can write, how he feels best. I wanna only tell my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams has a decent answer. You can also check the length of a filtered list:

```
if len([p for p in (param_a, param_b, param_c) if p]) != 1:
    print("Invalid.")
```

Which would be even shorter if you happened to have a list of params:

```
if len([p for p in params if p]) != 1:
    print("Invalid.")
```

Comment: That won't work if the parameters can have false-ish values like 0, '', [], etc.

Answer (score 0):

How many are set?
Make a list of all the ones which are set, and see how long it is:

```
len([p for p in (param_a, param_b, param_c) if p != None]) == 1
```

It's like Ignacio's answer, but this doesn't rely on implicitly casting True to an integer and then summing it, so I think it's a bit clearer on intent to find the length of a list rather than the sum of anything.

[Edit as suggested by @pm-2ring to handle that a query string such as `?a=foo&b=&c=bar` could reasonably become `b=''` and my original check would have counted `b` as "not set" instead of "set to empty string"].

Comment: That won't work if the parameters can have false-ish values like 0, '', [], etc.

Comment: Agreed, but this is a web API, and a HTTP request's parameters are all going to be text, surely?

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, ok. But an empty string may be a valid parameter, and may need to be treated differently to `None`

Comment: @PM2Ring Good point; answer updated